# Как перенести приложение с spring data на hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

я столкнулся с проблемой переноса приложения с одной технологии на другую, если верить тому, что я вычитал

> Hibernate является JPA-совместимым, SpringJPA Spring-совместимым. Ваш HibernateJPA DAO может использоваться с JavaEE или Hibernate Standalone, когда SpringJPA может использоваться в Spring - SpringBoot, например

тоесть чистый hibernate используется для совсем другого стека технологий , а в spring приложении мы используем его через spring data, так же все примеры которые я находил "spring boot + hibernate" используют spring data jpa и datasource bean, которые связаны так springJpa -> hibernate -> datasource(JDBC) исходя из ответа на мой предыдущий вопрос. В общем я не нашел ни одного примера spring boot приложения где бы взаимодействие с бд выполнялась так 
1)мы создаем фабрику сессий читая "hibernate.cfg.xml" 
2)мы отдельно для каждого обращения открываем и закрываем сессию 
3)и исполняем внутри запросы
и в общем мне не особо понятно как сконфигурировать такое приложение 
вот у меня есть application.properties 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот hibernate.cfg.xml
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и я так понимаю что application.properties в данном случае вообще лишний(но он конфигурирует spring app) ведь коннект к бд у нас описан в xml , да и сами свойства hibernate тоже
Пожалуйста, пролейте свет на данный вопрос, каким образом мне уйти от spring data jpa к hibernate (для всех запросов ранее я использовал JpaRepository или прописывал сам пользуясь а теперь мне надо организовать это все на чистом hibernate без spring data

Comment: Рассмотрите Pom и application.properties тут - https://github.com/Antonio112009/HibernateAuthenticationExample

Comment: Пример не идеальный, но вдруг поможет

Comment: @Antonio112009 ,спасибо

Comment: Помогло или вы еще не смотрели?

Comment: Вот что происходит, когда сразу начинаешь учить "высокоуровневые" технологии. С `Hibernate`-ом, конечно, можно работать не только через `Spring Data JPA`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#orm-hibernate

Comment: @notaProgrammer, я с ним работал и не через springData , но то был не spring проект